# Pythonw exe spam when using conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I was trying to create a new conda environment using:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
```

Everything seems ok for a few minutes while conda downloads all of the packages.  However, after the last download my PC was hanging.  I check task manager and there were > 1200 instances of `pythonw.exe` and climbing.  I had to kill them as everything was grinding to a stop.

After getting the PC back to normal I checked to see if it created the environment with `conda info --envs` The py35 environment was there but when listing the packages it was incomplete.  So I tried removing it with:

```
conda remove --name py35 --all
```

And again I got an ever growing spam of hundreds of `pythonw.exe`

I tried the standby reboot the machine and reattempted the whole process ... and same thing.

Has anyone run across this before?  Have an idea what could be causing it?

FYI, I am using Windows 7,  conda version is 4.3.5, and root environment is python 3.4.5

Comment: Maybe "spam" isn't the best term to use in your title/description (since your question has nothing to do with spam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with `pythonw.exe` permissions. The recommended workaround is to install Anaconda for each user in their user directory.

[see this github issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/menuinst/issues/42)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Unfortunately since I am in a locked down corporate environment getting them to change the default install location for a SW package is problematic ... however at least I have a github issue to reference to get the bureaucracy gears grinding in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I too found that running either `conda remove --name <env_name> --all` or `conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda` would spawn a seemingly infinite amount of `pythonw.exe` processes. Here is what I did to fix this:

1. I ran `conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda` in `cmd.exe`.
2. Then, as expected, during the `Solving package specification...` message, the `pythonw.exe` processes starting spawning.
3. **WITHOUT STOPPING CONDA**, I opened up the Task Manager.
4. I right clicked on one of the `pythonw.exe` processes.
5. Choosing the `End Process Tree` option, I then held down the Enter button to close the habitually reoccurring Windows notifications.
6. Once the notifications stopped popping up, the conda program executed normally once again.

I have no idea why or how this worked, but it did. Here's hoping that this helps.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't kill them all.  I can't run anything that uses `pythonw`.  If i try to use Spyder via that start menu shortcut (uses pythonw) it causes the same issue.  If I launch it via cmd.exe using `python` instead it works fine.